# Database Querying from Controller Returning Query not Values

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first, epplus

*Vs'12, asp.net MVC4 Internet Application, EF Code First, MySQL db*

**Overview**

I am trying to create a report with `EPPlus` from a Controller level. - User clicks button program gets here, i need to query the database for some information..

**Explanation**

I tried this way: *Where intPR=1 as a passed in variable*

```
var pro = from p in db.Prospect
        where p.ProspectID == intPR
        select p;
var cty = from c in db.Countys
        from p in db.Prospect
        where p.ProspectID == intPR
        select c;
```

then I would use something like this to set it to the field

```
string x = pro.Select(p => p.ProspectName).ToString();
          ws.Cells["E" + LineFeed].Value = x;

string xx = cty.Select(m => m.County).ToString();
          ws.Cells["E" + LineFeed].Value = xx;
```

All i get is the super long query string

```
"SELECT 
[Extent1]...... You get the hint
```

**Question**

Why am i not getting values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using LINQ, the expression only gets evaluated when the results are really needed. Note that select actually returns an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`. It's only if actually want to use the values that it executes the query. The default `ToString()` method just prints the query.

You could for example call the `ToList()` method to make sure the query is exectuted:

```
var prospects = pro.Select(p => p.ProspectName).ToList();
```

However, this will return a list of prospects, calling the `ToString()`-method on that would still yield just the name of the type. If you want the first item of the list you can do the following:

```
var firstProspectName = pro.Select(p => p.ProspectName).First():
```

**EDIT**: Your query could be written a bit more concise, without intermediate steps:

```
var firstProspectName = db.Prospect.where(p => p.ProspectID == intPR)
                                   .Select(p => p.ProspectName)
                                   .First();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer, I used your answer and just added in `pro.ToList();` under my query, is this considered "OKAY" or should i use your route `var pro = db.Prospect.Select(p => p.ProspectName).ToList();` from the git go?

Comment: That is OK, but you could optimise it a bit more. I have added an example to my answer on how you could write it a bit more concise.